# Formulas insertion in excel 2013 over 2 sheets

Tags: excel-formula

I am working in excel 2013 with 6 sheets sheet 1 is a summary Sheets 2-6 are days of the week. it is an incentive program for the plant. is it possible to use a name from sheet one (summary) and have excel search pages 2-6 to find that specific name and return a dollar amount from (Colum f on Sheets 2-6)

Answer (score 0):

The dollar amount is the sum from the incentives throughout the week right?

Assuming the names are listed at Column A as well, you can use multiple sumif:

> =SUM(SUMIF(Sheet2!A1:A100,Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!F1:F100),
>   SUMIF(Sheet3!A1:A100,Sheet1!A1,Sheet3!F1:F100),
>   SUMIF(Sheet4!A1:A100,Sheet1!A1,Sheet4!F1:F100),
>   SUMIF(Sheet5!A1:A100,Sheet1!A1,Sheet5!F1:F100),
>   SUMIF(Sheet6!A1:A100,Sheet1!A1,Sheet6!F1:F100))